# Numerical errors when solving Ax=b in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra, numerical-stability

I am attempting to solve the system `Ax = b` in MATLAB, where `A` is a 30x30 triangular matrix with (nonzero) values ranging from `1e-14` to `0.7`, and `b` is a 30-element column vector with values ranging from `1e-3` to `1e3`.  When I enter `x = A\b`, I get an answer and no warning messages, but the answer is not reasonable (looks like just random numbers at the bottom of the vector). I presume this is due to numerical errors.

Message 5 on [this page](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/170919)  suggests decomposing/scaling the matrix in order to avoid numerical errors, but I haven't been able to figure out how to calculate the scaling matrices.

So the question is: Is this indeed an example of numerical instability, and if so, how can I rescale my matrix A, or change how MATLAB is performing the calculation, to avoid it?

---

Here is the matrix and vector that are producing the issue:

```
A = 

Columns 1 through 15

     0.69       0.4278      0.19893     0.082223     0.031861     0.011852    0.0042866    0.0015187   0.00052965   0.00018243    6.221e-05   2.1038e-05   7.0653e-06   2.3587e-06   7.8344e-07
        0       0.4761      0.44277      0.27452      0.14183     0.065953     0.028624     0.011831    0.0047156    0.0018273   0.00069233   0.00025755   9.4356e-05   3.4126e-05   1.2206e-05
        0            0      0.32851      0.40735       0.3157      0.19573      0.10618     0.052668      0.02449     0.010846     0.004623    0.0019108   0.00077007   0.00030383   0.00011773
        0            0            0      0.22667      0.35134      0.32675      0.23635      0.14653     0.081766     0.042246      0.02058    0.0095696    0.0042851    0.0018597   0.00078615
        0            0            0            0       0.1564      0.29091      0.31564      0.26093        0.182      0.11284     0.064129      0.03408     0.017168    0.0082788    0.0038496
        0            0            0            0            0      0.10792      0.23418      0.29039      0.27006       0.2093      0.14274     0.088499      0.05095      0.02764     0.014281
        0            0            0            0            0            0     0.074464      0.18467      0.25761       0.2662      0.22694      0.16884       0.1134     0.070311     0.040868
        0            0            0            0            0            0            0      0.05138      0.14335      0.22219      0.25256      0.23488      0.18931      0.13694     0.090965
        0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0     0.035452       0.1099      0.18738      0.23235       0.2341       0.2032      0.15748
        0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0     0.024462     0.083415      0.15515      0.20842      0.22614      0.21031
        0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0     0.016879     0.062789      0.12652      0.18303      0.21277
        0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0     0.011646     0.046935      0.10185      0.15786
        0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0     0.008036     0.034876     0.081087
        0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0    0.0055448     0.025783
        0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0    0.0038259
        0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
        0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
        0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
        0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
        0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
        0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
        0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
        0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
        0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
        0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
        0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
        0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
        0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
        0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
        0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0

Columns 16 through 30

   2.5906e-07    8.5327e-08    2.8007e-08   9.1646e-09   2.9906e-09   9.7342e-10   3.1613e-10   1.0246e-10   3.3142e-11   1.0702e-11   3.4504e-12   1.1108e-12   3.5709e-13   1.1465e-13   3.6767e-14  
   4.3246e-06   1.5194e-06   5.2988e-07   1.8359e-07   6.3236e-08   2.1667e-08   7.3883e-09   2.5085e-09   8.4833e-10   2.8585e-10   9.5998e-11    3.214e-11    1.073e-11   3.5726e-12   1.1866e-12
    4.492e-05   1.6909e-05   6.2902e-06   2.3156e-06    8.445e-07   3.0543e-07   1.0963e-07   3.9084e-08   1.3847e-08   4.8779e-09   1.7094e-09   5.9615e-10   2.0698e-10   7.1568e-11   2.4651e-11
   0.00032494   0.00013173   5.2503e-05   2.0616e-05   7.9887e-06   3.0592e-06   1.1591e-06   4.3497e-07   1.6181e-07   5.9715e-08   2.1877e-08   7.9615e-09   2.8794e-09   1.0354e-09   3.7037e-10
    0.0017358   0.00076232   0.00032721   0.00013766     5.69e-05   2.3151e-05   9.2878e-06    3.679e-06   1.4406e-06   5.5824e-07   2.1426e-07   8.1515e-08   3.0763e-08   1.1523e-08   4.2867e-09
    0.0070833    0.0033935     0.001578   0.00071495   0.00031662   0.00013741   5.8573e-05   2.4566e-05   1.0154e-05   4.1418e-06   1.6691e-06   6.6527e-07   2.6248e-07   1.0259e-07   3.9755e-08
     0.022523      0.01187    0.0060211    0.0029554    0.0014095   0.00065541   0.00029799   0.00013279   5.8116e-05   2.5022e-05   1.0615e-05   4.4423e-06   1.8361e-06   7.5031e-07   3.0339e-07
     0.056398     0.033024     0.018428    0.0098671     0.005098    0.0025529    0.0012436   0.00059114   0.00027488   0.00012531   5.6113e-05   2.4719e-05   1.0728e-05   4.5926e-06   1.9414e-06
      0.11158     0.073506     0.045573     0.026843      0.01513    0.0082078    0.0043059    0.0021929    0.0010877   0.00052686   0.00024979   0.00011615   5.3064e-05   2.3852e-05   1.0563e-05
      0.17385      0.13089     0.091294     0.059747     0.037043     0.021923     0.012459    0.0068335    0.0036315    0.0018763   0.00094518   0.00046536   0.00022441   0.00010618   4.9374e-05
      0.21107      0.18539      0.14778      0.10881     0.074955     0.048796     0.030253     0.017976     0.010288    0.0056949    0.0030601    0.0016008   0.00081734   0.00040822   0.00019981
      0.19575      0.20632      0.19188      0.16145      0.12513     0.090508     0.061727      0.04001     0.024806     0.014788    0.0085139    0.0047507    0.0025773    0.0013629   0.00070418
      0.13406      0.17663      0.19712       0.1935      0.17139      0.13947      0.10569     0.075354     0.050967     0.032916     0.020408     0.012201    0.0070603     0.003967    0.0021702
     0.063943      0.11233       0.1567      0.18459      0.19074      0.17739      0.15122       0.1198     0.089133     0.062798     0.042179     0.027157     0.016837     0.010091    0.0058655
     0.018977     0.050003     0.093006      0.13695      0.16982      0.18425      0.17952      0.15999      0.13226       0.1025     0.075107     0.052387     0.034978     0.022461     0.013926
    0.0026399     0.013912     0.038815     0.076207      0.11812      0.15379      0.17481      0.17806      0.16559      0.14259      0.11493     0.087452     0.063257     0.043745     0.029059
            0    0.0018215     0.010164     0.029933     0.061862      0.10068      0.13733      0.16319      0.17345      0.16803      0.15048      0.12595     0.099387     0.074457     0.053266
            0            0    0.0012569    0.0074028     0.022949     0.049799     0.084907      0.12108      0.15014      0.16622      0.16747      0.15575      0.13519      0.11049     0.085626
            0            0            0   0.00086723    0.0053768     0.017502     0.039787      0.07092      0.10553      0.13631      0.15695      0.16421      0.15837      0.14237      0.12037
            0            0            0            0   0.00059839    0.0038955     0.013284     0.031571     0.058722     0.091019      0.12227       0.1462      0.15862      0.15845      0.14736
            0            0            0            0            0   0.00041289    0.0028159     0.010039     0.024896     0.048236     0.077756      0.10847       0.1345      0.15115      0.15618
            0            0            0            0            0            0   0.00028489    0.0020313    0.0075564     0.019521     0.039334     0.065845     0.095256      0.12234      0.14222
            0            0            0            0            0            0            0   0.00019658    0.0014625    0.0056673     0.015226     0.031861      0.05531     0.082873       0.1101
            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0   0.00013564    0.0010512    0.0042363     0.011819     0.025648     0.046115     0.071478
            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0    9.359e-05   0.00075433    0.0031569    0.0091339     0.020528     0.038183
            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0   6.4577e-05   0.00054051    0.0023458    0.0070296     0.016344
            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0   4.4558e-05   0.00038676    0.0017385    0.0053894
            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0   3.0745e-05    0.0002764    0.0012852
            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0   2.1214e-05   0.00019729
            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0   1.4638e-05  


b = 
       3712
       246.89
       43.304
        22.55
       14.897
       10.066
       6.8138
       4.6131
       3.1232
       2.1146
       1.4316
      0.96927
      0.65623
      0.44429
       0.3008
      0.20365
      0.13788
     0.093351
     0.063202
      0.04279
      0.02897
     0.019614
     0.013279
    0.0089906
     0.006087
    0.0041211
    0.0027902
     0.001889
    0.0012789
   0.00086589
```

A .mat file with the full-precision variables may be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8iofupruh9i9xq6/vars.mat?dl=0).

---

Here are the results I'm getting on my machine (Matlab R2013a on OS X 10.10.5):

```
>> x=A\b

x =

       5087.6
       433.99
       64.166
       27.995
       19.494
       14.546
       10.934
       8.2265
       6.1834
       4.6933
       3.2779
       3.8272
      -3.5375
       23.953
      -79.278
       254.22
       -702.1
       1713.2
      -3658.2
       6822.7
       -11046
        15412
       -18349
        18393
       -15244
        10181
      -5273.4
       1992.3
      -489.85
       59.155
```

Although `norm(A*x-b)` returns a value on the order of 1e-13, the results are not physically reasonable given the problem I am trying to solve (values in x should be monotonically decreasing, and none should be negative).  As an example, here is a similar dataset that returns a correct (looking) solution with the same matrix A:

```
>> c

c =

       5142.1
       339.52
       22.417
       1.4802
     0.097731
    0.0064529
   0.00042607
   2.8132e-05
   1.8575e-06
   1.2265e-07
   8.0979e-09
   5.3469e-10
   3.5304e-11
    2.331e-12
   1.5391e-13
   1.0162e-14
   6.7099e-16
   4.4304e-17
   2.9253e-18
   1.9315e-19
   1.2753e-20
   8.4205e-22
   5.5598e-23
    3.671e-24
   2.4239e-25
   1.6004e-26
   1.0567e-27
   6.9771e-29
   4.6068e-30
   3.0418e-31

>> x = A\c

x =

       7029.1
       653.25
       60.709
        5.642
      0.52434
      0.04873
    0.0045287
   0.00042087
   3.9114e-05
    3.635e-06
   3.3782e-07
   3.1395e-08
   2.9177e-09
   2.7116e-10
     2.52e-11
    2.342e-12
   2.1765e-13
   2.0227e-14
   1.8798e-15
    1.747e-16
   1.6236e-17
   1.5089e-18
   1.4023e-19
   1.3033e-20
     1.21e-21
   1.1339e-22
   9.9766e-24
   1.1858e-24
   2.3902e-26
    2.078e-26
```

Comment: Show us the numerical data the produced the problem.

Comment: @NKN, I have added the data (and thanks to Sardar_Usama for helping format).  Please re-open this question - it deals with an important issue related to use of MATLAB.

Comment: Your `A` matrix is not 30-by-30, but 30-by-31, despite the column number labels. Please check your data. It would also be better if you posted a MAT file containing the variables with their full precision.

Comment: Also, while `x` may not "look reasonable" to you, it is -- just look at the residual norm `norm(A*x-b)`, which for your data is on the order of 10^-12.

Comment: @horchler Sorry about that, a column got duplicated while pasting.  I've fixed it.

Comment: @CKT: I've added clarification of what results I expect and an example that behaved "correctly."

Comment: `rcond(A)` is `4.32770678808031e-09` so this is pretty much exactly what I would expect

Comment: @Adriaan - I have edited to clarify the question.

Comment: @dannyhmg `vpa(sym(A)\sym(b),100)` returns the answer very similar to the purely numerical one, discrepancy is on the order of `1e-9`. So, I guess, the error you get is due to the dataset.